# Updating date on every get request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking for more elegant way to update my record every time get request hits my API. There is a promotion with time limit, so every time someone enters website, activation status should get updated according to current date. My current code works, but I'm pretty sure it's far too complex and might have serious performance issues.

```
exports.getAllPromotions = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const allPromotions = await Promotion.find({});
        allPromotions.forEach(async promotion => {
            promotion.isActive = checkIfActive(
                promotion.startingDate,
                promotion.endingDate
            );
            await promotion.save();
        });
        const updatedPromotions = await Promotion.find({});
        return res.status(200).json(updatedPromotions);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

Comment: A `GET` request should never ever modify your data on the server.

Comment: OK, so I can split that to 2 request - POST to update status, and GET after that, but it still doesn't change my problem - I still need a way, to update status on backend, so noone can mess up on front with promotions.

Comment: what kind of check is `checkIfActive` is doing, because you maybe be able to simplify this into 1 `updateMany` query, at the moment this is extremely inefficient

Comment: Actually I changed that controller and removed isActive from database. Now I just add isActive to response object and do the check every time get request is made.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it doesn't matter if you update some value in get request. In fact, I would prefer it instead of sending another request because the second request might not reach to the server.
Alos, I believe `forEach` doesn't wait for the promise (`await`) to resolve. You can use `Array.map()` to get the expected result it. This way, your `.save` function would run in parallel/concurrently. You can read this article about [Promise.all](https://anotherdev.xyz/promise-all-runs-in-parallel/) and when it runs things in parallel or concurrently.

```
const allPromotions = await Promotion.find({});
const promises = allPromotions.map(promotion => {
    promotion.isActive = checkIfActive(
        promotion.startingDate,
        promotion.endingDate
    );
    return promotion.save();
});

await Promise.all(promises);

const updatedPromotions = await Promotion.find({});
```